# How can I get the corners of a stroke to be a sharp point?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke

I have this logo and it has some really sharp corners:

[image]

When I add a stroke some of them get square:

[image]

Why does that happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: What program are you using?

Answer (score 3):

With the object selected, from the Stroke panel set the corner style to Miter Joint, then adjust the miter limit (10 by default) until you get the effect you want.
EDIT: Pretty sure it works:
[image]

Comment: i tried that, doesnt work

Comment: You have to make sure your corners have only a singly anchor point and that those points are closed.

Comment: @AlejandraBarrera Make sure that the Corner Limit is at a high value. To prevent infinite points, Ai truncates any miter that would exceed the limit you set.

Comment: In their infinite wisdom, Adobe has hidden all the stroke options by default. You need to click hamburger and show options